# Angular 8: not able to get message from Rest Api

Tags: html, django, angular, typescript

I used following links https://grokonez.com/python/django-angular-6-example-django-rest-framework-mysql-crud-example-part-2-django-server and https://grokonez.com/frontend/django-angular-6-example-django-rest-framework-angular-crud-mysql-example-part-3-angular-client to create a django rest API and angular app that calls this rest.

Considering that I'm new in such kind of development so I created as a first step an App that just displays customers list.
Django rest API is fine working. I tested it with the browser:

[image]

But my problem is with the angular app, seems that it's not able to get message with the same URL: http://localhost:8000/customers
Below is my angular code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomersListComponent } from './customers-list/customers-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents,
    CustomersListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomersListComponent } from './customers-list/customers-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'customers', component: CustomersListComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**customer.ts**

```
export class Customer {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    active: boolean;
}
```

**customer.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {
    private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/customers';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getCustomersList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/`);
    }

}
```

**customers-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { CustomerService } from '../customer.service';
import { Customer } from '../customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers-list',
  templateUrl: './customers-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomersListComponent implements OnInit {

    customers: Observable<Customer[]>;


    constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Hellllllllo from customers-list.component.ts ngOnInit");
         this.reloadData();
    }

    reloadData() {
        this.customers= this.customerService.getCustomersList();
    }

}
```

**customers-list.component.html**

```
<h1>Customers {{JSON.stringify(this.customers)}}</h1>

<div *ngFor="let customer of customers" style="width: 300px;">
    <h2>Hello iii</h2>
    <div>
    <label>Name: </label> {{customer.name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Age: </label> {{customer.age}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Active: </label> {{customer.active}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The result that got when calling /customers from the browser is the following:

[image]

"Routing and Navigation" message is coming from app.component.html
As you can see message Customers is displayed but everything that corresponds to the variable customers (which is the list of customers) is not displayed.

Has someone an idea what's the main cause of this issue? and how I can fix it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: use subscribe in your component and then get your response there.

Answer (score 0):

You should `subscribe` to get the response from the API because `http.get` returns an observable, observable invokes only when you subscribe to it. try the following method

```
 reloadData() {
   this.customerService.getCustomersList().subscribe((res: any) => {
       this.customers = res;
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service

```
getCustomersList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/`);
    }
```

This function returns an observable
So you should subscribe to it like this to make the request

```
 this.customerService.getCustomersList().subscribe((res: any) => {
       this.customers = res;
   });
```

Or in your html file you can add async pipe like this

```
*ngFor="let customer of customers | async
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed for your answer, but it doesn't solve the issue, it's the same behaviour